# prove that $a\mid b$ is not a partial order

Tags: proof-writing

prove that $a\mid b$ is not a partial order on integers $\mathbb{Z}$

I'm really lost how should I prove that?

Comment: You should start by writing down what "|" means, and what "partial order" means.

Comment: I changed $a|b$ to $a\mid b$, coded as a \mid b in $\LaTeX$.  The spacing is different.  If you're caught defacing monuments with graffiti, then the same police office who will give you a stern lecture about correct spelling will tell you that the latter form is correct.

Comment: @Michael, Romanes eunt domus.

Comment: In about the second half of this video a cop lecture a graffiti artist about spelling: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZg7tQ7KykM

Comment: @Michael, I thought you were referring to this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIAdHEwiAy8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not antisymmetric.

For instance $-1 \mid 1$ and $1 \mid -1$ but $1 \neq -1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\sim$ is a partial order, then

$$\tag 1 a\sim a$$ for every $a$ and $$\tag 2 a\sim b,b\sim c \implies a\sim c $$

and **finally**  $$\tag 3 a\sim b, b\sim a \implies a=b$$

Which one of these three properties fail? And which two hold?

Note however that $\;\; \mid \;\;$ **is** a partial order on $\Bbb N$.